# python how to combine scripts without writing multiple files

Tags: python

ok so this may seem trivial, but essentially what I want to learn is how to combine my scripts without always writing another file just to reopen it and write another; thus, creating a useless paper-trail(even if it is electronic).

so say I can create two functions, write to a file, reopen it and start another function in the same script and write it to another file.  I would like to skip the first write and second open.

In other words I do not want to require the output1/output2 process.  Maybe save the first text as a string inside a variable and reopen it?

so here is a generic code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def do_something():
    f= open('input.txt', 'r')
    f0=open('output1.txt', 'w')
    lines=f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line= line.replace("x","y")
        f.write(line)

def do_anotherthing():
    f0=open('output1.txt', 'r')
    f1= open('output2.txt', 'w')
    lines=f0.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line=line.replace ("z", "a")
        f0.write(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_something()
    do_anotherthing()
```

Comment: Do you know that functions can [accept arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions) and [return](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) results?

Comment: @alko I still don't get what he's trying to do.

Comment: This question is poorly written with no clear requirements of what's being achieved here.

Comment: sorry about the clarity. I just want to do two separate things on one .txt and write only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use arguments and return statements?

```
def do_something():
    f= open('input.txt', 'r')
    lines=f.readlines()
    s = []
    for line in lines:
        line= line.replace("x","y")
        s.append(line)
    return s

def do_anotherthing(buffers):
    f1= open('output2.txt', 'w')
    lines=buffers
    for line in lines:
        line=line.replace ("z", "a")
        f1.write(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_anotherthing(do_something())
```

Answer (score 1):

Split your functions so that they do *one thing*.

```
def switch_x_with_y(line):
    return line.replace("x", "y")

def replace_z_with_a(line):
    return line.replace("z", "a")

f_output = open("output.txt", "w")
for line in open("input.txt", "r"):
    line = replace_x_with_y(line)
    line = replace_z_with_a(line)
    f_output.write(line)
```

Most importantly, split off the file handling stuff from the actual processing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's hard to understand what you're asking.

Maybe you're looking for somthing like this?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def do_lot_of_stuff(funcs):
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as in_file, \
         open('output1.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        for line in in_file.readlines():
            for func in funcs:
                line = func(line)
            out_file.write(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_lot_of_stuff([lambda line: line.replace("x","y"),
                     lambda line: line.replace("z", "a")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is poorly written. Any way if you want to keep data and do some processing you can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html) `DataFrame`s.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import read_csv

df = pd.read_csv('input.txt')
df.columns = ['col'] #I suppose you don't need to split data

df['col'] = misc['col'].str.replace('x', 'y')
```